# Transferring at Heathrow Terminal 2 and re-checking bags - how long does it take?

Tags: transit, luggage, lhr, short-connections

How much time should I allow for a flight connection in Heathrow? I'll be arriving and departing from Terminal 2, but the flights are on two separate tickets. The first airline has said they won't check my bag in all the way to my final destination.

I will need to pick it up at Heathrow and recheck; Heathrow's online flight connection plan doesn't work for this scenario as it doesn't mention picking up luggage. Would it be feasible to do this in two hours?

Answer (score 1):

If your first flight won't check your bag all the way to your final destination that means you need to pass though passport control at Heathrow and collect your bag from the carousel. You then need to head into departures, check in your bag for your next flight and go through security again. You won't be able to transfer airside.